# Strongly typed selectors in swift

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

I wonder can we implement strongly typed selectors in swift? For example if i have a method named `buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject)` in my view controller later when we add that method as target to some button can we just say

```
button.addTarget(self, selector:ViewController.buttonTapped(self), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: there is no concept of "selector" in Swift. ideally, closure should be used for such purpose.

Comment: I know there isn't. But can we add an extension to `Selector` type and make it parse methods?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can add extension to `UIButton` with method like `addAction(action:UIButton->Void forControlEvents events:UIControlEvent)`

Comment: @BryanChen if you showed an implementation of your addAction method as an answer, I would up vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 2.2 have compile time checked selectors using the `#selector` syntax, see https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/ and [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID59)

For your example, it would be written this way:

`button.addTarget(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`

Answer (score 10):

#### Outdated. See [Claus Jørgensen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39054350/642626) for Swift 2.2+

There is no concept of "selector" in Swift. Ideally, closure should be used for such purpose.

What you really want is something like this

```
button.addAction(forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) {
   // watch out for retain cycle, use weak or unowned accordingly
    ViewController.buttonTapped(self)
}
```

and you can have it with this code (untested, but it should give you a start point)

```
public class ClosureWrapper : NSObject
{
    let _callback : Void -> Void
    init(callback : Void -> Void) {
        _callback = callback
    }
    
    public func invoke()
    {
        _callback()
    }
}

var AssociatedObjectHandle: UInt8 = 0

extension UIControl
{
    public func addAction(forControlEvents events: UIControlEvents, withCallback callback: Void -> Void)
    {
        let wrapper = ClosureWrapper(callback)
        addTarget(wrapper, action:"invoke", forControlEvents: events)
        // as @newacct said in comment, we need to retain wrapper object
        // this only support 1 target, you can use array to support multiple target objects
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle, wrapper, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
    }
}
```

and hopefully in the future release of SDK, similar methods takes closure instead of selectors will be added by Apple, so we don't need to implement them ourself.

Comment: That won't work, because `UIControl` does not retain action targets, so it will be calling stuff on a deallocated instance.

Comment: @bryanchen this doesn't work for me. I included your snippet above my swift code at the top of the file. I do add action as you describe with         binderButton.addAction(forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside, withCallback: {
            abort()
        }). it doesn't abort, breakpoint doesn't hit.

Comment: This answer is now incorrect as of Swift 2.2, where #selector is available

Answer (score 0):

This is my Swift 2.0 version of the Bryan's great answer:

```
import UIKit

public class CallbackHolder: NSObject {

    let callback: () -> Void

    init(callback: () -> Void) {
        self.callback = callback
    }

    public func call() {
        callback()
    }

}

private let AssociatedObjectHandle = UnsafePointer<Void>()

extension UIButton {

    func addAction(forControlEvents events: UIControlEvents, withCallback callback: () -> Void) {
        let holder = CallbackHolder(callback: callback)
        addTarget(holder, action: "call", forControlEvents: events)
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, AssociatedObjectHandle, holder, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC) // prevent garbage collection
    }

}
```