# Why is my UIButton's target never reached?

Tags: swift, uibutton

```
    func setupNewBinderButton() {
    let binderButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    binderButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 384-25, 50, 50)
    binderButton.setTitle("Add", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    binderButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    binderButton.addTarget(self, action: "addBinderTapped", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    binderButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(binderButton)
    }



func addBinderTapped() {
    println("hi")
    abort()
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

setupNewBinderButton()
```

The breakpoint I set in this function doesn't get hit. The log doesn't get hit. The abort doesn't happen.

How do I make my UIButton respond to touches in Swift?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056278/swift-access-control-with-target-selectors/25056424#25056424

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449053/strongly-typed-selectors-in-swift/26454949#26454949

Comment: no dice. I tried using action:Selector("addBinderTapped:") and      @objc func addBinderTapped(button:UIButton!) { as the link references.

Comment: So in the second example, I have to add code just to get a button to register a function? There's got to be a way built in.

Comment: unfortunately there is no builtin way currently... may have to wait for next SDK release

Comment: I put your code in a new ViewController file and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I used an IBAction in the storyboard and it gets called.

Comment: your code is working properly. no problem in your code. try to check is there any other view's is overlapping on your button by which you may not be able to touch the button properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this as it needs to be tied to IBAction

```
@IBAction func addBinderTapped(sender: UIButton)
{
}
```

Connect this action with your button by command+drag to storyboard button to tie this function.