# How to accept a not-quite-generic, yet dynamic type as an argument for subclasses?

Tags: generics, swift, types, arguments

In light of [this question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73364/closure-as-uicontrolevents-handler), which was inspired by [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26454949/2792531), I come to back to Stack Overflow with this question.

Suppose I have a class with numerous subclasses, let's say `UIControl`.  I want to extend this class with a method.  This method should take, as one of its parameters, an object of its same type.  But for any and all of this classes subclasses, this method should only accept an argument of its own type.  For example, `UIButton` should accept only arguments of type `UIButton`, and `UILabel` should accept only arguments of type `UILabel`.

What has been tried?

First:

```
func foo<T: UIControl>(arg: T) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This works as far as compiles and runs, however it does no enforcing.  I can pass any `UIControl` subclass no matter what type I actually call `foo` on.

Next:

```
func foo(arg: Self) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Also:

```
func foo<T: Self>(arg: T) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Neither of these work, but it was a thought.  Does not compile, can't use `Self` like this.

Also tried:

```
func foo(arg: self.dynamicType) {
    // do stuff
}
```

And:

```
func foo(arg: typeof(self)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

And still none of these worked--won't compile (weird errors for these and reasonably so...).

Then:  I ran out of ideas.

Now, generally, we'd probably argue that using generics is fine, because we're only going to do things with it that the parent we constrained the generic to is capable of, but what if we want to return this object to something else who will know and need it as something more specific than its parent type we defined?

For example, if we're writing a function to add a callback:

```
func doCallBack<T: UIControl>(callback: (T) -> Void)) {
    callback(self)
}
```

It is important to us that within the callback block, the user is able to use and refer to the argument as its specific type, but it's also important to us that when we call `doCallBack` on a `UIButton` that `T`'s type can only be a `UIButton`, but when we call `doCallBack` on a `UILabel`, that `T`'s type can only be a `UILabel`, and etc for every type of `UIControl`.

Can this be accomplished at all?

Comment: My idea is to write a protocol and only implement it in the subclasses if necessary. And I think inheritance is exaggerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for any and all of this classes subclasses, this method should
>   only accept an argument of its own type.

This is not really possible with the way inheritance works.

Consider

```
class Foo : UIControl
class Bar : Foo
```

So `Foo` must have a method with signature `func foo(arg: Foo)`. And since `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo`, it will inherit a method with signature `func foo(arg: Foo)` (or override it with a method of that signature). In no case can the parameter type be narrower than `Foo`, because then `Bar` won't be a proper substitute for `Foo`, as required by inheritance. Therefore, `Bar`'s `foo` method cannot "only accept an argument of its own type".

Comment: On the one hand, this seems kind of obvious now that its spelled out.  On the other hand, coming from Objective-C and having no familiarity with generics (as I'm sure will be the case for others too), I'm a bit glad I asked this question.